# Why my animated webp image from my HTML5 email is not playing in Gmail?

Tags: html, gmail, html-email, webp

I use this code to display a animated webp in a HTML5 email. The image is playing in Outlook but not in Gmail. Size is 600x338px. Weight is around 15 Mo and duration is 15 secs. Is it a matter of weight?

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;border:none;max-width:600px;">
<tr align="center"> 
  <td> 
    <div style="text-align:center;background-image:url('GIF/LINK');background-size:20%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;margin:0 auto;position:relative;height:0;max-height:0;padding-bottom:56.33%;">
      <a href="WEBP/LINK" style="border:none;"> 
        <!--[if !mso]><!-- --> <img style="width:100%;border:none;max-width:600px;" src="WEBP/LINK" alt="VIDEO"> <!--<![endif]--> 
        <!--[if lte mso 16]> <img alt="VIDEO" border="0" src="VIDEO/LINK" style="border:none;width:0px;max-height:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;" width="600" height="338"/> <![endif]--> 
      </a> 
    </div> 
  </td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: By "video without sound" do you mean "animated webp *image*"?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:html5-video] but I don't see a `<video>` tag anywhere in your code.

Comment: Is the image appearing as a static image or is it not appearing at all?

Comment: @Quentin : there is a static black image. I am not sure if it is the first image of the video (wich is black) or a substitution black image. At my first try, the video was too heavy, nothing where showing but a file icon (as it is missing). Now the video is lower, I have this black image instead. 
About html5-video, I thought it is related somehow

Comment: @Quentin: I am not an expert but i suppose it is an animated webp image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail does not support webp animation; it converts the file to jpg: https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-webp/